# Detect different speakers in an audio recording

Tags: audio, voice-recognition, voice

I want to make an application that counts the speaking time of each speaker in an audio recording. I don't care about doing full voice recognition and transcribing every word in the recording, I just want the speaking time of each voice.

Is there a piece of software that provides such feature?

If possible, I would like to avoid using a third-party service (such as Google Cloud) to achieve this, and I would like the solution to be light enough to run on a modern smartphone.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same idea. Check this out https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio

Haven't tried it myself yet. Will add an edit after.